# Data type of Function with void return type and taking no input parameters

Tags: java, function, void, return-type

I am unable to figure what would be the return type of these functions `fooBar()` and `barFoo()`
in Java and getting the following errors.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

class FooBar {
  private void foo() {
  }

  private void bar(String s) {
  }

  public FunctionalInterface fooBar() {
    return this::foo;// The type of foo() from the type FooBar is void, this is incompatible with the
                     // descriptor's return type: Class<? extends Annotation>
  }

  public Function<String, Void> barfoo() {
    return this::bar;// The type of bar(String) from the type FooBar is void, this is incompatible
                     // with the descriptor's return type: Void
  }
}
```

Is there any way to return these functions, so that they can be used by other functions?

Setting return type to `FuncionalInterface` isn't helpful.
Setting return type to `Void`, but however it isn't compatible with `void`

Thanks!

Comment: Use a `Consumer<String>` declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are types which match `void f()` and `void f(String a)`. They are `Runnable` and `Consumer<String>` respectively.

So your code becomes:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

class FooBar {
    private void foo() {
    }

    private void bar(String s) {
    }

    public Runnable fooBar() {
        return this::foo;
    }

    public Consumer<String> barfoo() {
        return this::bar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Function` has a `<T,R>` generic type, you are looking for `Runnable` (a `void`, `void` function) and [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) (a `void`, `T` function). Like,

```
public Runnable fooBar() {
    return this::foo;
}

public Consumer<String> bar() {
    return this::bar;
}
```